# Thin border lines in MFC/MDI

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I would like to have thin child frame borders in my MFC/MDI application. [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x07xt611.aspx#_core_the_mdi_case) suggests changing window styles in PreCreateWindow function and it seems like proper window style is [WS_BORDER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx). However something like this doesn't work;

```
BOOL CChildFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    cs.style |= WS_BORDER;
    return CMDIChildWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are trying to add the style to the existing ones, it should be `|=`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Yes that's what I meant. It doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: You may need to remove other border styles.

Comment: I tried removing individually or combination of WS_CAPTION, WS_DLGFRAME, WS_SIZEBOX, WS_THICKFRAME and so on. If you can give me a specific suggestion that would help better. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't done any MFC programming for many years, and can't see why anyone would, these days. But have you tried explicitly setting the styles and other options you are interested in, rather than modifying the defaults?

Comment: *"this doesn't work"* is not a problem statement. Please be explicit in explaining the desired result as well as the actual result.

Comment: An MDI child window must always have a fat border.  MDI child windows need to be resizable, that's what the windowing model looks like.  Well, looked like :)

Comment: So, I think this is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
BOOL CChildFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
// TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying
//  the CREATESTRUCT cs

cs.style = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER;

if(! CMDIChildWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs))
    return FALSE;

return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: "WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER" style doesn't show Child window as a window. It looks like it's embedding it.